# Dynamically Select Column In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

The field I want to pull depends on the value of another field. I have a lookup table that looks like this:

| Prefix | A_value | B_value | C_value | D_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| B | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| C | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |

I am looking for a way to pull the appropriate value based on the Prefix column. Would be something like this:

`Select selected_column = Prefix + '_value'`

Where the desired result is:

| selected_column |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 6 |
| 11 |

I could easily achieve this with a bunch of CASE/WHEN expressions, but I wanted to see if there's a way to easily call the desired column dynamically.

Comment: And no, there's no *easy* dynamic way as you envision. In fact your design is simply flawed. You should better have every value in its own row but in one column. In another column there's be the designation ('A', 'B', 'C', ...) for each row and in yet another column the group identifier referencing another *table* having the groups with their identifier and their default designation. Then this could be a simple join. You need to learn to think "relational" not "spreadsheety" for successfully using relational databases.

Comment: Another side note: SSMS is just a client, not a DBMS. But it's used (mostly?) to connect to SQL Server (that's an actual DBMS), so I changed the tag for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if it really is `A_value` -> `Z_value`, you can use [`CHOOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql):

```
SELECT selected_column = CHOOSE
                         (
                           ASCII(Prefix)-64, 
                           A_value, 
                           B_value, 
                           C_value,
                           D_value
                         ) 
FROM dbo.[a lookup table];
```

- Example [db](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=195af4cc47d93b26c2811cccb47b2906)

Answer (score 2):

You could go the JSON route.

> ```
> select 
> cast(json_value(json_values, '$[0].'+Prefix+'_value') as int) as selected_column
> from your_lookup_table t
> cross apply (
>  select t.* 
>  for json path
> ) ca(json_values)
> ```

| selected_column |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 6 |
| 11 |

But if it only a few columns, then maybe using a `CASE` is the most straightforward method.

```
select
 case Prefix
 when 'A' then A_value
 when 'B' then B_value
 when 'C' then C_value
 when 'D' then D_value
 end as selected_column
from your_lookup_table
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a9168f417a200b9c40ec147f5a8faa10)*

Comment: A good solution as well.    Just a side note,  the dynamic attribute would fail in 2016.   +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Hey indeed, in 2016 it required an actual string literal.

Comment: Glad they corrected in 2017.  Just seemed like a no-brainer in 2016

Answer (score -2):

You can use CURSOR :

```
declare @t table (Prefix nvarchar(50),A_value int,B_value int,C_value int,D_value int)

insert into @t values ('A', 1,  2,  3,  4)
insert into @t values ('B', 5,  6,  7,  8)
insert into @t values ('C', 9,  10, 11, 12)

declare @result table (selected_column int)
declare @Prefix nvarchar(50),@A_value int,@B_value int,@C_value int,@D_value int

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Prefix,A_value,B_value, C_value,D_value
FROM @t 
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Prefix,@A_value,@B_value, @C_value,@D_value  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
 
BEGIN  
    insert into @result
    Select CASE
        WHEN @Prefix='A' THEN @A_value
        WHEN @Prefix='B' THEN @B_value
        WHEN @Prefix='C' THEN @C_value
        WHEN @Prefix='D' THEN @D_value
    END;
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Prefix,@A_value,@B_value, @C_value,@D_value 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor 

select * from @result
```

Comment: You *can*, but you most certainly shouldn't.

Comment: Please do not suggest Cursor to anyone until it is necessary. :)

Comment: Why he shouldn't ..? @Larnu

Comment: *They* shouldn't because SQL is a set based language, @BarbarosÖzhan  and so it excels at set based logic. A `CURSOR`, however, is the complete opposite to that methodology; it is iterative. As a result SQL performs incredibly poorly at such operations. There in, in truth, *very* few times when a `CURSOR` is the right choice, and this is certainly far from one of them.